# PHP Pass by reference confusion

Tags: php, pass-by-reference

To cut a long story short I have the following function as part of my framework:

```
public function use_parameters()
{
    $parameters = func_get_args();

    $stack = debug_backtrace();

    foreach($stack[0]['args'] as $key => &$parameter)
    {
        $parameter = array_shift($this->parameter_values);
    }
}
```

Where $this->parameter_values = array('value1', 'value2', 'value3', 'value4', 'value5', ...);

Which is used in the following context:

```
$instance->use_parameters(&$foo, &$bah);
```

Assigning:

```
$foo = 'value1';
$bah = 'value2';
```

Calling it again

```
$instance->use_parameters(&$something);
```

Will set

```
$something = 'value3'
```

and so on.

As of 5.3 it would return a 'Deprecated: Call-time pass-by-reference has been deprecated' warning. In an effort to conform to the 5.3 way of working I removed the &'s resulting in:

```
$instance->use_parameters($foo, $bah);
```

This unfortunately has caused the arguments not to be set and I'm struggling to come up with a solution.

For what its worth I'm running PHP v5.3.3-7 on Apache/2.2.16 (Debian)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Stop using references. Continued usage *will* cause pain an death.

Comment: I love the way there have been no comments on this for 20 minutes. Everybody is on a codepad trying to find a way to make it work. And it's not looking good, to be honest - I think I've now tested every possible permutation of `func_get_args()`, `func_get_arg()` and `debug_backtrace()` and I've not yet found any way to get references to the variables passed dynamically.

Comment: @NikiC: No need to go over the top. Liam is asking what are the alternatives/other workouts. He is open to suggestions.

Comment: @itachi It was not meant as criticism or something :) Just personal advice that whenever you fiddle with references you'll get screwed in one way or the other.

Comment: Btw, I plan to work on getting improved variadic function support into PHP 5.5. Then you could also make a function accepting by-ref varargs using a syntax like `function use_parameters(&... $params)`.

Comment: @NikiC I generally use references very sparingly so thankfully not had any issues until now.

Comment: @NikiC It would be great if func(&$param) was still supported but do you realistically think that the decision to deprecate it will be reversed?

Comment: Perhaps in the constructor you could put your parameters into `$this->parameters`. It could then be retrieved using `$this->getParameters()` at various points in this class; this way, it can be reset when you wish to amend its values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do that in PHP and you are abusing the concept of references.   You have to specify the reference arguments explicitly, albeit with default values.  *However*, you don't want to use NULL as a default as this is what an unassigned reference variable will be set to.  So you need to define some constant that you know is not going to be used as a parameter, and now the code will look something like

```
    const dummy="^^missing^^";

    public function use_parameters(&$a, &$b=self::dummy, &$c=self::dummy ) {
        $a=array_shift($this->parameter_values);
        if($b!==self::dummy) $b=array_shift($this->parameter_values);
        if($c!==self::dummy) $c=array_shift($this->parameter_values);
        # add $d,$e,$f,... as required to a sensible max number
    }
```

Note that because you are using references properly, you don't need the debug_backtrace() botch.

Comment: Yes.  Does my fragment do what you are wanting to do?

Comment: The whole point of using `NULL` is that it eliminates unassigned references (unless you want to accept `NULL` values, that is).

Comment: @Narf, you miss the point if we use your approach:  `$obj->use_parameters($x)` will only assign the next param to $x if $x has previously been assigned a (non-null) value, which is definitely _not_ what Liam wanted.

Comment: Wait, so ... the task here is not to assign the passed variables to some array, but the other way around?

Comment: Yup, as far as I read it what the OP is trying to do is something that I would code as `list($foo, $bah) = $instance->use_parameters(2);` or something like that.  The arguments are outputs to received the framwork parameters.  I may be wrong, but that's the way that I read it.

Comment: For what its worth it is used in a script that splits up a url for a CMS. I don't think this is going to look pretty in a comment but here goes:

Assuming the url is http://host/edit/3/foo/bah 

The script will populate the $parameter_values array with 'edit', '3', 'foo' and 'bah' values.

`$instance->use_parameters($mode, $id);

if($mode == 'edit')
{
    //Do something with $id ('3')
    
 //Maybe use $instance->use_parameters($something); to populate $something with 'foo'.
}`

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that in PHP 5 or ... as you've seen you can, but it's deprecated and raises warnings. You'll have to either have a predefined max count of function arguments or use an array:

```
public function use_parameters(&$arg1, &$arg2 = NULL, &$arg3 = NULL)
{
    // if ($arg2 !== NULL)
    // if ($arg3 !== NULL)
}

$parameters = array(0 => &$foo, 1 => &$bah);

public function use_parameters($args)
{
    // Handle the array elements
}
```

Comment: Fair enough - I was hoping to be able to do it dynamically (and cleanly) but if it's not possible, it's not possible.

Comment: you mean in PHP 5.3 it raises warnings